# Would TensorFlow utilize GPU on a Mac if installed on a VM?

Tags: macos, cuda, virtual-machine, gpu, tensorflow

From TensorFlow's ["Getting Started"](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md) page:

```
# Only CPU-version is available at the moment.
$ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

I'm not super familiar with using GPU or CUDA libraries, but if I installed TensorFlow inside a Linux VM (say the [precise32](http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box) available through Vagrant), then would TensorFlow utilize the GPU when running inside that VM?

Comment: CUDA only works with VMs if the VM supports  PCI-e pass- through. I have no idea whether such a VM is available for OS X

Comment: Do you have a dual gpu macbook pro? If not so you can't use it because gpu process is only available on Nvidia gpus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not.  VirtualBox, for example, [does not support PCI Passthrough on a MacOS host, only a Linux host](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html) (and even then, I'd... uh, not get my hopes up).  MacOS ends up so tightly integrated with its GPU(s) that I'd be very dubious that any VM can do it at this point.

Answer (score 4):

As an update: Tensorflow can now use GPUs on Mac OS X. The relevant PR is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/664 and after a `brew install coreutils` the Linux installation 'build from source' instructions should work. I see a 10x speedup compared to the CPU version with an NVIDIA gforce 960 and Intel i7-6700K.

Edit/(downdate?): Starting with MacOS Mojave, due some API changes and what appears to be some long-standing beef between Apple and NVidia, drivers for NVidia graphics cards are no longer available. No NVidia means no Cuda means no Tensorflow, nor really any other respectable machine learning. It appears something like Google Collaboratory is the way to go for now.

Comment: Is this included in 0.8 release? I did not see the Mac gpu binary.

Comment: Build from source only for now, I believe. It was merged into the main branch 7 days ago and .8 was released 10 days ago. Should be 0.9 – until then: building from source isn't too complicated.

Comment: Are there any TF 2.0 updates on running GPU code on Mac OS / VM?